# Zassenhaus formula in Mathematica

Tags: physics, series-expansion, algebra

I'm looking for Mathematica implementation of Zassenhaus [formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#Zassenhaus_formula) -- given two matrices $A,B$, truncate the expansion of $\exp(A+B)$ from this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.04681):

$$e^{t(A+B)}= e^{tA}e^{tB}\prod_{n=2}^\infty e^{t^n Z_n(A,B)}$$

What's the most elegant way to implement this in Mathematica?

Below is an evaluation of "zero-th order" truncation of this expansion for $A,B$ appearing in my application (diagonal + rank1), trying to see how many terms I need for a reasonable approximation error.

```
d = 100;
h = Normalize[#^-1.1 & /@ Range[d], Tr];

a0 = 2 h (1 - h);
b0 = h;

ones = ConstantArray[1., d];
t = -d;
A = DiagonalMatrix[a0];
e[mat_] := MatrixExp[mat];
norm[mat_] := Total[mat, 2];
B = -{b0}\[Transpose] . {b0};
{{norm@e[t (A + B)], "exact"},
  {norm[e[t A] . e[t B]], "order-0"}} // TableForm
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is my old implementation based on [M.WEYRAUCH, D.SCHOLZ, COMPUTER PHYSICS COMMUNICATIONS, 180, (2009), 1558-1565](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0010465509001222?via%3Dihub)

Returns 'unfolded' or 'folded' (in terms of commutators):

```
ND$ZASSENHAUS$UNFOLDED[2, {"X", "Y"}]
ND$ZASSENHAUS$UNFOLDED[3, {"X", "Y"}]
ND$ZASSENHAUS$UNFOLDED[4, {"X", "Y"}]
ND$ZAS[4, X, Y, F]
(* -((XY)/2)+(YX)/2  *)
(* (XXY)/6-(XYX)/3-(XYY)/3+(YXX)/6+(2 YXY)/3-(YYX)/3 *)
(* -((XXXY)/24)+(XXYX)/8+(XXYY)/8-(XYXX)/8-(XYXY)/4-(XYYY)/8+(YXXX)/24+(YXYX)/4+(3 YXYY)/8-(YYXX)/8-(3 YYXY)/8+(YYYX)/8  *)
(* {X,Y,-(1/2) F[X,Y],-(1/6) F[F[X,Y],X]-1/3 F[F[X,Y],Y],-(1/24) F[F[F[X,Y],X],X]-1/8 F[F[F[X,Y],X],Y]-1/8 F[F[F[X,Y],Y],Y]} *)
```

Example for matrices:

```
(* compute terms *)
ClearAll[X, Y, F] ;
order = 8 ;
terms = ND$ZAS[order, X, Y, F] // Rest // Rest ;

(* set random input & compute exact output *)
SeedRandom[1] ;
t = 0.1 ;
a = RandomReal[{0.0, 1.0}, {2, 2}] ;
b = RandomReal[{0.0, 1.0}, {2, 2}] ;
c = MatrixExp[t * (a + b)]  ;

(* O(t^2) *)
result = MatrixExp[t*a] . MatrixExp[t * b] ;
Norm[result - c]
(* 0.001777447231126185` *)

(* higher order *)
result = Table[result = result . MatrixExp[terms[[i]] /. {X ->t*a, Y ->t* b, F -> Function[{x, y}, x . y -y . x]}] , {i, 1, Length[terms]}] ;
Map[Norm[# - c] &, result]
(* {0.00005544291090346927`,2.773628721869079`*^-6,7.421340761934133`*^-8,1.375336002537211`*^-9,3.593262198290658`*^-11,1.2194115693175485`*^-12,2.3818383250085455`*^-14} *)
```

Main code:

```
(* ################################################################################ *)
(* BCH AND ZASSENHAUS (M.WEYRAUCH, D.SCHOLZ, COMPUTER PHYSICS COMMUNICATIONS, 180, (2009), 1558-1565) *)
(* ND$BCH$UNFOLDED[TERM,{LEFT,RIGHT}] *)
(* ND$ZASSENHAUS$UNFOLDED[TERM,{LEFT,RIGHT}] *)
(* ND$CONVERT$UNFOLDED[TYPE,TERM,{LEFT,RIGHT},HEAD] *)
(* ND$BCH[TERM,LEFT,RIGTH,HEAD,MODE] *)
(* ND$ZAS[TERM,LEFT,RIGTH,HEAD] *)
(* ND$TRUNCATED$EXP[TERM,LEFT,RIGHT,HEAD,MODE] *)
(* ################################################################################ *)

(* ################################################################################ *)
(* AUXILIARY FUNCTION FOR BCH AND ZASSENHAUS *)
ClearAll[ND$WORDS] ;
ND$WORDS[ND$P_List, ND$ALPH_List] := StringJoin[Apply[ConstantArray,Partition[Riffle[ND$P,ND$ALPH,List[1,Times[2,Length[ND$P]],2]],2],List[1]]] ;
(* ################################################################################ *)


(* ################################################################################ *)
(* UNFOLDED BCH (GOLDBERG'S METHOD) *)
ClearAll[ND$G] ;
ClearAll[ND$C] ;
ClearAll[ND$BCH$UNFOLDED] ;
ND$G[1] = 1 ;
ND$G[ND$S_] := ND$G[ND$S] = Expand[1/ND$S*D[ND$T*(ND$T-1)*ND$G[ND$S-1],ND$T]];
ND$C[ND$W_] := ND$C[ND$W] = Block[{ND$M = Length[ND$W],ND$P = Floor[Length[ND$W]/2],ND$Q = Floor[(Length[ND$W]-1)/2],ND$K},Integrate[ND$T^ND$P*(ND$T-1)^ND$Q*Product[ND$G[ND$W[[ND$K]]],{ND$K,ND$M}],{ND$T,0,1}]] ;
ND$BCH$UNFOLDED::usage="ND$BCH$UNFOLDED[TER,{LEF,RIG}] " ;
ND$BCH$UNFOLDED[ND$N_,ND$ALPH_] := Block[{ND$P = Flatten[Map[Permutations,IntegerPartitions[ND$N]],1]},Expand[Total[Map[ND$C[Sort[#]](ND$WORDS[#,ND$ALPH]-(-1)^ND$N ND$WORDS[#,Reverse[ND$ALPH]])&,ND$P]]]] ;
(* ################################################################################ *)


(* ################################################################################ *)  
(* ZASSENHAUS, (COMPARISON METHOD) *)
ClearAll[ND$TPOWER] ;
ClearAll[ND$TPRODUCT] ;
ClearAll[ND$TSCALAR] ;
ClearAll[ND$TTRANSFORM] ;
ClearAll[ND$ZASSENHAUS$UNFOLDED] ;
ND$TPOWER[ND$X_,0] := List[List[1,""]] ;
ND$TPOWER[ND$X_,1] := ND$X ;
ND$TPOWER[ND$X_,ND$N_/;ND$N>1] := Nest[Map[List[Times[Extract[#,{1,1}],Extract[#,{2,1}]],StringJoin[Extract[#,{1,2}],Extract[#,{2,2}]]]&,Flatten[Outer[List,#,ND$X,1],1]]&,ND$X,ND$N-1] ;
ND$TPRODUCT[ND$X_] := Fold[Map[List[Times[Extract[#,{1,1}],Extract[#,{2,1}]],StringJoin[Extract[#,{1,2}],Extract[#,{2,2}]]]&,Flatten[Outer[List,#1,#2,1],1]]&,First[ND$X],Rest[ND$X]] ;
ND$TSCALAR[ND$C_,ND$X_] := Map[List[ND$C First[#],Last[#]]&,ND$X] ;
ND$TTRANSFORM[ND$X_List] := Total[Apply[Times,Flatten[ND$X,1],List[1]]] ;
ND$TTRANSFORM[ND$X_String] := List[List[1,ND$X]] ;
ND$TTRANSFORM[ND$X_Plus] := Apply[List,Apply[List,ND$X],List[1]] ;
ND$ZASSENHAUS$UNFOLDED::usage="ND$ZASSENHAUS$UNFOLDED[TER,{LEF,RIGH}] " ;
ND$ZASSENHAUS$UNFOLDED[2,ND$ALPH_List] := ND$ZASSENHAUS$UNFOLDED[2,ND$ALPH] = - StringJoin[ND$ALPH]/2+StringJoin[Reverse[ND$ALPH]]/2 ;
ND$ZASSENHAUS$UNFOLDED[ND$N_/;ND$N>2,ND$ALPH_List] := ND$ZASSENHAUS$UNFOLDED[ND$N,ND$ALPH] = Block[
    {
        ND$A1,ND$A2,ND$A3,ND$A4,ND$A5,ND$A6,ND$A7,ND$A8,ND$A9
    },
    ND$A5 = IntegerPartitions[ND$N] ;
    ND$A7 = Rest[Map[BinCounts[#,List[1,ND$N,1]]&,ND$A5]] ;
    ND$A8 = Flatten[Map[(ND$A3=ND$A6=First[#];Table[Join[List[ND$A4=ND$A6--,ND$A3-ND$A4],Rest[#]],{ND$A3+1}])&,ND$A7],1] ;
    ND$A2 = Map[ND$TTRANSFORM,Join[ND$ALPH,Table[ND$ZASSENHAUS$UNFOLDED[ND$j,ND$ALPH],{ND$j,2,ND$N-1}]]] ;
    ND$A5 = Flatten[Map[Permutations,ND$A5],1] ;
    ND$A9 = Total[Join[Map[ND$WORDS[#,ND$ALPH]/Factorial[ND$N]&,ND$A5],Map[ND$WORDS[#,Reverse[ND$ALPH]]/Factorial[ND$N]&,ND$A5]]] ;
    ND$A1 = MapThread[ND$TSCALAR,{Map[Apply[Times,(1/Factorial[#])]&,ND$A8],Map[ND$TPRODUCT[MapThread[ND$TPOWER,{ND$A2,#}]]&,ND$A8]}] ;
    ND$A9 - ND$TTRANSFORM[ND$A1]
] ;
(* ################################################################################ *)


(* ################################################################################ *)
(* POLYNOMIAL CONVERTER FOR BCH AND ZASSENHAUS, (I.M., 2014-2015) *)
ClearAll[ND$CONVERT$UNFOLDED] ;
ND$CONVERT$UNFOLDED::usage="ND$CONVERT$UNFOLDED[TYP,TER,{LEF,RIG},HEA] " ;
ND$CONVERT$UNFOLDED[
    ND$TYPE_,     (* ND$BCH$UNFOLDED OR ND$ZASSENHAUS$UNFOLDED *)
    ND$N_,        (* NUMBER OF LETTERS (INTEGER > 1) *)
    ND$LETTERS_,  (* CHARACTERS FOR ALGEBRA ELEMENTS {<CHAR1>,<CHAR2>} *)
    ND$HEAD_      (* COMMUTATOR HEAD *)
] := Block[
    {
        ND$POLY,
        ND$LISTA,
        ND$LISTB,
        ND$A,
        ND$B,
        ND$TMP,
        ND$SENTENCES,
        ND$RESULT
    },  
    ND$HEAD[ND$a_,ND$b_,ND$c__] := ND$HEAD[ND$HEAD[ND$a,ND$b],ND$c] ;
    ND$POLY = Apply[List,ND$TYPE[ND$N,ND$LETTERS]] ;
    ND$LISTA = Part[ND$POLY,All,1] ;
    ND$LISTB = Part[ND$POLY,All,2] ;
    ND$TMP = StringCases[ND$LISTB,StringExpression[StartOfString,StringJoin[ND$LETTERS],___]] ;
    ND$SENTENCES = Flatten[ND$TMP] ;
    ND$A = Part[ND$LISTA,Take[Flatten[Position[ND$TMP,_String]],{1,-1,2}]] ;
    ND$B = StringCount[ND$SENTENCES,First[ND$LETTERS]] ;
    ND$RESULT = Total[ND$A/ND$B Map[Apply[ND$HEAD,ToExpression[StringCases[#, Repeated[_,1]]],List[0]]&,ND$SENTENCES]] ;
    Clear[ND$HEAD] ;
    ND$RESULT
] /; ND$N > 1 ;
(* ################################################################################ *)


(* ################################################################################ *)
(* CONVERTED BCH *)
ClearAll[ND$BCH] ;
ND$BCH::usage="ND$BCH[TER,LEF,RIG,HEA,MOD] " ;
ND$BCH[
    ND$N_,         (* -- NUMBER OF TERM *)
    ND$A_,         (* -- LEFT *)
    ND$B_,         (* -- RIGHT *)
    ND$HEAD_,      (* -- COMMUTATOR HEAD *)
    ND$MODE_:True  (* -- OUTPUT FORMAT *)
    (* True (DEFAULT) -- LIST OF TERMS UP TO <ND$N>  *)
    (* False -- ONLY <ND$N> TERM *)
] := Block[
    {
        x,
        y,
        ND$I$1,
        ND$I$2
    },
        ND$I$1 = If[ND$MODE,2,ND$N] ;
        ND$I$2 = ND$N ;
        ReplaceAll[
            If[
                ND$MODE,
                Join[List[ND$A+ND$B],#],
                First[#]
            ] & @ Map[ND$CONVERT$UNFOLDED[ND$BCH$UNFOLDED,#,{"x","y"},ND$HEAD]&,Range[ND$I$1,ND$I$2]],
            Thread[Rule[List[x,y],List[ND$A,ND$B]]]
        ]
] ;
(* ################################################################################ *)


(* ################################################################################ *)
(* CONVERTED ZAS *)
ClearAll[ND$ZAS] ;
ND$ZAS::usage="ND$ZAS[TER,LEF,RIG,HEA,MOD] " ;
ND$ZAS[
    ND$N_,         (* -- TERM NUMBER *)
    ND$A_,         (* -- LEFT *)
    ND$B_,         (* -- RIGHT *)
    ND$HEAD_,      (* -- COMMUTATOR HEAD *)
    ND$MODE_:True  (* -- OUTPUT FORMAT *)
    (* True (DEFAULT) -- LIST OF TERMS UP TO <ND$N>  *)
    (* False -- ONLY <ND$N> TERM *)
] := Block[
    {
        x,
        y,
        ND$I$1,
        ND$I$2
    },
        ND$I$1 = If[ND$MODE,2,ND$N] ;
        ND$I$2 = ND$N ;
        ReplaceAll[
            If[
                ND$MODE,
                Join[List[ND$A],List[ND$B],#],
                First[#]
            ] & @ Map[ND$CONVERT$UNFOLDED[ND$ZASSENHAUS$UNFOLDED,#,{"x","y"},ND$HEAD]&,Range[ND$I$1,ND$I$2]],
            Thread[Rule[List[x,y],List[ND$A,ND$B]]]
        ]
] ;
(* ################################################################################ *)
```

Comment: Thanks! background for this problem is given [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2902848)